# Between *variable sharing* and *command substitution*, which method is better for returning a value from another bash script

Tags: bash, shell

Suppose I have

- a bash script `A.bash`, which calls another script `B.bash`.
- `B.bash` calculates a variable `VAR`.
- Now I would like `B.bash` to return `VAR` to the calling script.

I can *export* `VAR` in `B.bash` and *source* `B.bash` in `A.bash`. Another solution is to *echo* `VAR` in `B.bash`, *execute* `B.bash` in `A.bash` and get the the return value as `R=$(B.bash)`.

Does it make sense? Which option is better? Are there any alternatives?

Comment: Since you know the solution, how could we help you?

Comment: Yep, that's pretty much all there is (btw, you don't have to `export` anything if you *source* the inner script)

Comment: I've gived an answer as I think there is a question about programming practice: *Does it make sense? Which option is better* At all my answer could be developped (for answering 1st of 3;) but I don't understand why they was closed! Please explain a little? @Guru Take a look at my answer, there is not **one** solution only and differences could become significant.

Comment: @F.Hauri  I added the questions `Does it make sense ? ...` after Guru's comment.

Comment: So, yes it do! ;-) Sometime `$()` is usefull, mostly for interaction with binaries, but writting a shell script may result in different performances depending on how it was thinked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Little introduction

Tracking forks (like `$()`)  as they consume lot more ressource than normal (sequential) execution, if you know which variable has to be modified in advance, you'll better to use `local` definition around your whole script and use function instead of having to make file access between commands:

```
#!/bin/bash
# There is the `A` script

local VAR

function B() {
    read -a VAR </proc/uptime
}

B
echo $VAR
sleep 1
B
echo $VAR
```

could output something like:

```
1610291.39
1610292.39
```

with time to access `/bin/sleep` could be less than 1/100th of second.

#### A little demonstration:

```
local V1
B1() {
    read -a V1 </proc/uptime
}
B1 ;echo $V1 ;for i in {0..10000} ;do B1 ;done ;echo $V1
1610843.78
1610844.38
printf "%d 1/100th of sec\n" $((161084438-161084378))
60 1/100th of sec
```

I could set 10000x my variable in 60/100 seconds, while

```
B2() {
    local var
    read -a var </proc/uptime
    echo $var
}
V2=$(B2);echo $V2;for i in {0..10000};do V2=$(B2);done;echo $V2
1611121.33
1611168.01
printf "%d 1/100th of sec\n" $((161116801-161112133))
4668 1/100th of sec
```

May take **more** time!

If you really wanna keep all in separated file, as @alok suggested, you could `source` them, as this will not fork:

```
echo >/dev/shm/B3 'read -a V3 </proc/uptime'
. /dev/shm/B3 ;echo $V3 ; for i in {0..10000};do . /dev/shm/B3;done;echo $V3
1612187.89
1612188.79
printf "%d 1/100th of sec\n" $((161218879-161218789))
90 1/100th of sec
```

This is lot quicker than having to fork for each loop, but accessing to function via filesystem (even RAM pseudo filesystem, without access time) take some time.

### My answer

1. Yes, it make sense, while `$(...)` or `...` stay usefull for returning result of a binary command or other strong script with a lot of bariables you won't inherit.
2. Depending on your need and who wrote each parts... paralelism... other factors...
3. Other alternatives, for dynamic command, not really, but don't miss to use *built-ins* like `mapfile` or `read -a` when you can.

### Disclaimer

This concern [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) only! If you want your script to be *portable* (even if `bash` is already ported on most significant os), you have to not use *array variables* and try your script with `zsh` or `dash`.

Answer (score 2):

Shell scripts by convention return 0 when successful else non zero.

Your best bet is to pass this via a shell variable.

`A.bash` :

```
unset VAR
source B.bash
echo $VAR
```

`B.bash` :

```
export VAR=value
```

Answer (score 1):

When I use bash functions I do it like this:

```
function myfunc()
{
    local  myresult='some value'
    echo "$myresult"
}

result=$(myfunc)   # or result=`myfunc`
echo $result
```

Hope that helps.